# XSL creation to grab only certain nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

Just a quick one I hope, I'm trying to create an XSL for the following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CurrentUsage xmlns="http://au.com.amnet.memberutils/"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <OtherLimit>0</OtherLimit>
   <PeerLimit>0</PeerLimit>
   <PeriodEnd>2013-06-15T00:00:00</PeriodEnd>
   <PeriodStart>2013-05-15T00:00:00</PeriodStart>
   <PlanName>ADSL 2+ Enabled 120G/180G - $69.00</PlanName>
   <RateLimited>0</RateLimited>
   <otherInGB>9.51</otherInGB>
   <otherOutGB>2.06</otherOutGB>
   <peerInGB>0.12</peerInGB>
   <peerOutGB>0.02</peerOutGB>
</CurrentUsage>
```

What I would like to get out of it is just the content of...

- otherInGB
- outherOutGB
- peerInGb
- peerOutGb
- A total of these 4 values combined (if possible with just XSL).

I've tried numerous different XSL documents (I'm no expert) but I'm getting stuck because it appears to me that there isn't really a parent node. Is that a correct statement?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:for-each select="CurrentUsage">
    <xsl:value-of select="otherInGB"/>
    <br></br>
    <xsl:value-of select="otherOutGB"/>
    <br></br>
    <xsl:value-of select="peerInGB"/>
    <br></br>
    <xsl:value-of select="peerOutGB"/>
    <br></br>
                  </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know this is wrong as it doesn't return anothing and I know that the for-each select is actually causing the problem. Anyways any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Trent

Comment: It's not really clear what should your output look like. Do really like to have the node names in (otherOutGB etc.) in output or the text content of this nodes nodes (9.51, etc.)

Comment: Hi hr_117. Sorry the content within the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue here is that your xml file has an name space. Therefore you need to add the name space (with a prefix) to your xslt.
Try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:mu="http://au.com.amnet.memberutils/"
                exclude-result-prefixes="mu">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mu:CurrentUsage">
        <xsl:value-of select="mu:otherInGB"/>
        <br></br>
        <xsl:value-of select="mu:otherOutGB"/>
        <br></br>
        <xsl:value-of select="mu:peerInGB"/>
        <br></br>
        <xsl:value-of select="mu:peerOutGB"/>
        <br></br>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mu:CurrentUsage " />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
9.51<br/>2.06<br/>0.12<br/>0.02<br/>
```

Comment: hr_117. You are a star. Works perfectly! I owe you big time/ made my day!